# SQL Server: Grant execute without grant dml

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-permissions

I have a db user that has only db_reader permission. (He has SELECT on everything).

I have 100 stored procedures. I want him to have the ability to execute only the SELECT SP and not DML. Unfortunately, granting him 'execute' on all - allows him to also perform DML (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).

Is there a way around it?

(I don't want to run on all SP and give him specific grants on specific functions because I want it to also support future changes and future SPs)

Comment: Dont understand why I got a -1. Thought it was a legitimate question.

Comment: I don't understand either, so I upvoted to balance it out.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a role in the database
- use the code below to add the role to
  each of the "select" stored
  procedures

  use [YourDBNameHere]
  GO
  GRANT EXECUTE ON [TheSchemaNameHere].[YourSPNameHere] TO [YourRoleNameHere]
  GO
- Add the use to the role
- remove user permission of "select from everything"

Comment: Then I have to hand-pick the SPs. Which is a pain for future development.

Comment: @Faruz by adding the group you only have to pick the sp one time. Add the users to the group.  Never work with users only groupts, but you know that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is that SPs change every build, there are new ones, updated ones and rarely even removed ones. So I need to maintain this list every build which is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clever way, no matter if it's a pain as per other comments

- permission separately (in other answers)
- use schemas (in other answers)
- use a trigger on all your tables

And [DENY or db_denydatareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563186/sql-server-2005-db-denydatawriter-example-query/4563242#4563242) won't work at the table level

A stored proc can run any code: there is no way to distinguish a select or a DML proc.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions in SQL Server can be applied per-schema.  Put your SELECT procs into a separate schema and allow EXEC permissions on it.

Comment: Then I have to hand-pick the SPs. Which is a pain for future development.

Comment: Well that's what you have to do.